# What is node-libs-browser and why is it being installed when I install babel-loader

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have just installed [babel loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), to use babel with webpack.

It brings in 3 additional node dependencies, however only 2 of these I expected

from the babel loader [package.json](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/blob/master/package.json)

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "*",
  "webpack": "*"
},
```

So why am I also getting **node-libs-browser** I don't know what it is, and don't want the extra module in my devDependencies

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser for those interested

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**IMPORTANT!** As pointed out by Patrik, Webpack can deal with it now so you don't need to install it separately. It has been moved as a direct dependency of Webpack.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

**node-libs-browser** is a peer dependency of Webpack. As stated in the [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libs-browser) it provides certain Node libraries for browser usage. Obviously modules such as `fs` won't be available there but you can still use quite a few.

It is recommended that you maintain the versions of peer dependencies like this yourself. In fact that's going to be the default starting from npm 3. For now they get installed automatically. Therefore it's a good idea to have them listed explicitly at `devDependencies` even if that might feel like some extra work at the moment.

Comment: This has been resolved on the webpack side – it's now a normal dependency – with this pull request: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/1197

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Updated accordingly.